# Fine tuned VGG-16 gives the exact same prediction for all test images

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I have fine-tuned a VGG-16 network to predict the presence of disease on medical images. I've then tested the model by using `model.predict()` but what I'm seeing is that the network predicts the exact same ***22.310%*** and ***77.690%*** for the presence and absence of disease, respectively, for *all 100 test images* (see screenshot.) I'm attaching my code and training output below. The training looks okay. Please note, the training was done on a server and the prediction on my PC hence the directories are different.
Can you please help me find what the problem might be?

[image: RESULT]

Training code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import time
from vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from imagenet_utils import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import merge, Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

# Loading the training data
PATH = '/mount'
# Define data path
data_path = PATH 
data_dir_list = os.listdir(data_path)

img_data_list=[]
y=0;
for dataset in data_dir_list:
    img_list=os.listdir(data_path+'/'+ dataset)
    print ('Loaded the images of dataset-'+'{}\n'.format(dataset))
    for img in img_list:
        img_path = data_path + '/'+ dataset + '/'+ img 
        img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
        x = image.img_to_array(img)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        x = preprocess_input(x)
        x = x/255

        y=y+1
        print('Input image shape:', x.shape)
        print(y)
        img_data_list.append(x)
img_data = np.array(img_data_list)
#img_data = img_data.astype('float32')
print (img_data.shape)
img_data=np.rollaxis(img_data,1,0)
print (img_data.shape)
img_data=img_data[0]
print (img_data.shape)

# Define the number of classes
num_classes = 2
num_of_samples = img_data.shape[0]
labels = np.ones((num_of_samples,),dtype='int64')

labels[0:3001]=0
labels[3001:]=1

names = ['YES','NO']

# convert class labels to on-hot encoding
Y = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes)

#Shuffle the dataset
x,y = shuffle(img_data,Y, random_state=2)
# Split the dataset
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)

image_input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

model = VGG16(input_tensor=image_input, include_top=True,weights='imagenet')

model.summary()

last_layer = model.get_layer('block5_pool').output
x= Flatten(name='flatten')(last_layer)
x = Dense(16, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
x = Dense(8, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='output')(x)
custom_vgg_model2 = Model(image_input, out)

# freeze all the layers except the dense layers
for layer in custom_vgg_model2.layers[:-6]:
    layer.trainable = False

custom_vgg_model2.summary()

custom_vgg_model2.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

t=time.time()
#   t = now()
hist = custom_vgg_model2.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=10, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
print('Training time: %s' % (t - time.time()))
(loss, accuracy) = custom_vgg_model2.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=10, verbose=1)

print("[INFO] loss={:.4f}, accuracy: {:.4f}%".format(loss,accuracy * 100))
custom_vgg_model2.save("vgg_3000_92percent_real.h5")
```

Training output:

> Train on 4800 samples, validate on 1200 samples
>       Epoch 1/10
>       4800/4800 [==============================] - 100s - loss: 0.6098 - acc: 0.7567 - val_loss: 0.3252 - val_acc: 0.8667
>       Epoch 2/10
>       4800/4800 [==============================] - 82s - loss: 0.2644 - acc: 0.8985 - val_loss: 0.2930 - val_acc: 0.8783
>       Epoch 3/10
>       4800/4800 [==============================] - 83s - loss: 0.2297 - acc: 0.9127 - val_loss: 0.2386 - val_acc: 0.9042
>       Epoch 4/10
>       4800/4800 [==============================] - 83s - loss: 0.1844 - acc: 0.9327 - val_loss: 0.2273 - val_acc: 0.9083
>       Epoch 5/10
>       4800/4800 [==============================] - 83s - loss: 0.1754 - acc: 0.9354 - val_loss: 0.2080 - val_acc: 0.9167
>       Epoch 6/10
>       4800/4800 [==============================] - 83s - loss: 0.1357 - acc: 0.9515 - val_loss: 0.2403 - val_acc: 0.9183
>       Epoch 7/10
>       4736/4800 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1241 - acc: 0.9525

The prediction code

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
from imagenet_utils import preprocess_input
from keras import models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

model128 = models.load_model('16_8_finally.h5')
list=[]
flag=0
#Path0="D:\\download dump for Deep learnng\\dataset\\kaggle general competition\\test"
Path0="I:\\greenchTestsample\\greendr"
list=os.listdir(Path0)
pred0=[0]*len(list)
pred1=[0]*len(list)
for x in list:
    img_path=Path0+'\\'+ x 
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = preprocess_input(x)
    x=x/255
    preds = model128.predict(x)
    z=100*preds
    x1=float(z[0][0])
    x2=float(z[0][1])
    pred0[flag]=x1
    pred1[flag]=x2
    flag=flag+1
```

Comment: Where are you incrementing `flag` in the prediction loop? Looks like you're overwriting the zeroth element of `pred0` and `pred1` all the time. Wouldn't explain everything but clearly an issue.

Comment: Use `for i, x in enumerate(list):` and then `pred0[i] = x1` and `pred1[i] = x2`. `enumerate(list)` provides a counter that increments automatically as you traverse `list`.

Comment: @Peter Szoldan I forgot to copy the increment of flag statement to the forum

Comment: @Engineero: good idea! Still wouldn't explain why *all elements* of `pred0` and `pred1` are filled with the same value. Do you have any insight on that? Maybe `[0]*len(list)` creates a list with number objects referring to the same? Looks like she's on Windows, can this be the issue?

Comment: @PeterSzoldan: good point. Maybe `list` is the issue and she's getting the same filename several times? Perhaps use `img_path = os.path.join(Path0, x)` instead? Maybe print out the filename that you are loading in each loop to verify that you are getting what you think you are.

Comment: @sachsom Sorry, my edit just got approved, and it overwrote your edits. Can you please redo the addition of code you did as your last edit?

Comment: @PeterSzoldan I have re-edited it.Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is not really an answer but a step towards debugging. Please change the prediction loop to the code below and post the output.

```
for x in list[ :3 ]: # let's do the first 3 only
    img_path=Path0+'\\'+ x 
    print() # leave an empty line before each image
    print( image_path ) # let's see if the correct files are loaded
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = preprocess_input(x)
    x /= 255 # just nitpicking :)
    print( x ) # let's see if the values make sense
    preds = model128.predict(x)
    print( preds ) # see if the error is already present here
    z=100*preds
    x1=float(z[0][0])
    x2=float(z[0][1])
    print( x1, x2 )
    pred0[flag]=x1
    pred1[flag]=x2
    flag += 1 # nitpicking again :)
```

Comment: Results for pred0 are >77.69013214111328,77.69013214111328,77.69013214111328
Pred1>22.309873580932617,22.309873580932617,22.30987358093

Comment: also more than the predict function is it problem of fine-tuning of the model? I have trained with 3000 images per class

Comment: Do the image paths make sense, i.e., are you loading different images? Also the output from the numeric vectors of the images, are those different too?

Comment: Yes, it's also possible you have a model collapse. But generally I found it to be better to go from the trivial to the complicated when debugging. If you suspect model collapse, you should print a few predictions during training. If those are also 22.3 and 77.7 then yes, that's model collapse. But that requires rerunning the finetuning, so I'd check these trivial things first.

Comment: then shouldn't the validation accuracy reduce?Also how can I avoid it because I have trained with many fully connected configurations and parameter changes still the final result is not satisfactory

Comment: I trained again using 'adam' optimizer since it has smaller learning rates and numbers changed from 77 to 96 but apart from that everything is same.

Comment: As a good friend of mine once said, "Don't guess, experiment!" :) When you retrained, have you printed some predictions while training? That would tell you if there was a problem with your model.